# AuthorizeAttribute MVC, restricted based on user types?

Tags: authentication, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there a way to use the AuthorizeAttribute to restrict access base on user type? I have an admin login and an intern log in.

As of right now, both of these logins will show all tabs on my admin page. what I want is to restrict the # of tabs that the intern login sees.

Can I use the AuthorizeAttribute to do that? Please advise.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `AuthorizeAttribute` is placed on controller or action methods to prevent them from executing for unauthorize individuals.

In your case, what you want to do is prevent a menu from being displayed based on the type of users.

For this, you would use Roles that determine what permissions each user has.

Then on the view, you would use the `User.IsInRole("roleName")` to determine if they are in the role and act accordingly.

For instance, here is how you would only show the "Manage Users" menu item to an admin:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"))
{
   <li><a href="/admin/users">Manage Users</a>
}
```

Also, in the `Users` action method, you would decorate it with the AuthorizeAttribute to prevent users that are not in the "Admin" role from accessing the page.

```
[Authorize(Roles("Admin"))]
public ActionResult Users()
{
   //...
}
```